# What is the format of a Windows Phone Advertising ID string? What is the typical length?

Tags: windows-phone-8, udid, apple-id, idfa, android-identifiers

What are examples of the Device ID unique to Windows Phones?

As I do not have a Windows phone, I cannot look up any values myself.

Specifically I'm wondering about the typical length of Advertising IDs that Windows uses that are similar to IDFAs/AppleIDs/AndroidIDs/GooglePlay/UDID/etc.

For example, IDFAs are strings that are 36 characters in length and have the format XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX, where X = hexedecimal digit.

What is the similar format used by Windows Phones for unique IDs for advertisers?

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.advertisingmanager.advertisingid.aspx) simply states:

> The advertising ID is represented as an alphanumeric string. When the advertising ID feature is turned off, this is an empty string.

The actual length of the string does not appear to be documented at present.

Comment: Yes, this documentation was all that we could find on the internet after an intense Google search.  Surely there is SOME kind of format, though?  Knowing that the string is alphanumeric isn't really helpful for our particular application, unfortunately.  We're trying to filter out bad IDs.  Thanks for the link, though.

Comment: How would you get a "bad" id? Sounds like you're trying to solve a different problem here?

Comment: I work for an internet advertising company that receives bids from publisher exchanges -- opportunities to bid on mobile inapp ads.  We get bad IDs all the time (fraud, null values, etc.)  An example would be all 0s with the right hyphens.  It looks like a legit ID, but 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 is completely bogus, so we want to filter out stuff like that.  In order to filter these out, I need to know what good IDs look like for Windows Phones